# Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, remote-desktop, gnome

I found this post - [Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#850359)

But I'm still having issues, even with a freshly formatted computer.

I've edited the chrome-remote-desktop file (Dropbox download link to my edited version) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6w2nepbm4pmtc9l/chrome-remote-desktop?dl=0

After I enter a PIN and attempt to enable Remote Connections, it spins and spins saying 'Enabling Remote Connections' but nothing ever finishes/takes.

I've followed all the directions outlined in this post from beginning to end, in terms of procedural steps - https://medium.com/@akarpo/hi-vicken-c1fcea4514d6

Answer (score 0):

I ended finding an answer by editing the Chrome config file a bit further - [Configuring Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#comment1966661_850359)

And it ended up working!